# UI-Router with different master pages?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use ui-router, but based on the url or parameters, it can load different parent(master) page? 
for example

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <!-- We'll also add some navigation: -->
    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</body>
```

Apparently,Index.html is my master page for all my state in ui-routing. Is there anyway I can change the master page (index_mobile.html)? based on some parameters or states system received? It looks like it's impossible.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Perhaps provide and example?

Comment: Yeah, i would say you cannot do this. Why would you want to do this? If you must have two sets of views. Setup named views and load different templates into each. Set classes on the views and show/hide them with media queries. Strange way to do things though...